# Robot Framework - run powershell which replaces value in ini file

Tags: powershell, process, robotframework

I have a problem with my Robot Framework test case in which I have:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  Process

*** Test Cases ***

Change my ini file
  run process  powershell.exe  ${CURDIR}/test.ps1

*** Variables ***
${CURDIR}  C:/RobotFramework
```

---

${CURDIR} is C:/RobotFramework and there is my test.ps1 which contains:

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\RobotFramework\my.ini") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^Test.*', ('Test=10')} | Set-Content 'C:\RobotFramework\my.ini'
```

Script itself works correctly when I start it this way in ps commandline:
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\RobotFramework\test.ps1'

Test Cases passes with OK status, but it doesn't change that Test to 10 in my.ini file.
Please tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for my own problem :D

I tried with:

Change my ini file

```
  ${test}  Run And Return Rc And Output  powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\RobotFramework\\test.ps1"

  log to console  ${test}
```

and it works! :D